# How to disable compass usage in Google Maps for iOS?

Tags: ios, google-maps

I found this in [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#my_location):

> By default, no location data is shown on the map. You may enable the
>   blue "My Location" dot and compass direction by setting
>   myLocationEnabled on GMSMapView.

However, as it's stated, when I set `myLocationEnabled` to `YES`, both user location and compass direction are visible. Is there a way to keep user location but prevent compass arrow from appearing on the map? I don't use it in my project and I would like to save some battery by not using things I don't really need in my app.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Honestly, I think the impact on battery life is minimal, if not zero. I am not an iOS kernel expert, but I believe that the chip is always reporting the data to the system, so if your app calls the compass API or not shouldn't really have any influence on battery life.

Comment: Yeah I knowl I was just wondering about that.. Thanks:)